# click a element exist into foreach loop in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, foreach

I have a foreach in html and I want to click on a div for any items foreach ...but it did not work...
please help me..

```
 foreach (KarosazWeb.Models.HeaderItem img in Model.headerslider2) {

<div class="about-item scrollpoint sp-effect2" id="subjectClick" style="border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;border-color:#73d0d6;border-width:3px;border-radius:2px; background-color:#ffffff;background:#73d0d6">
  <h4 id="msat4" style="font-family:Tahoma;color:#ffffff">@img.header</h4>
  <h4 id="msat4" style="font-family:Tahoma;border-bottom:solid;border-color:#fff;color:#43749c; border-width:1px;margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px"></h4> @for (int i = 0; i
  < img.subItem.Count; i++) { <div id="subjectClickwd" @*value="@img.subItem[i].pTextID" *@ readonly rows="auto" style=" direction:rtl; background-color:#def2fa;font-family:font-nazanin;color:#1162a4;font-weight: bold;cursor:pointer;font-size:22px;text-align:right; text-align:justify ;outline-style:none; resize:none; width:100%; border:none;padding:8px;height:auto">
  @img.subItem[i].textLink</div>
<textarea rows="3" id="note" style="direction:rtl; font-family:font-nazanin;font-size:23px;text-align:right; text-align:justify ;margin-top:0px;border-bottom-right-radius:0px;border-bottom-left-radius:0px; resize:none; width:100% ;outline-style:none; border:none;padding:10px">@img.subItem[i].summary</textarea>
}
<input type="button" value="@img.header" class="form-control" id="" />
</div>

<br /> 
}
```

and into jQuery script:

```
$('#subjectClick').click(function () {

            var subInput = $('#subInput').val();
            alert(subInput);
            var funcUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/Home/SubjectClick?subInput=' + subInput;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', url: funcUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#paragraph').hide();
                    $('#paragraphTXT').show();
                    $('#text').text(data.text);
                    $('#subject').text(data.sub);
                }, error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error in json SubjectClick clicking");
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers to get you started.

- ID elements in a page should be unique. ("subjectClickwd" is an id
  attribute for the div element in this case and will be having more
  than one element in this case)
- At the time of event binding the elements are still not present, so
  you will have to resort to event delegation, so that the future
  elements can handle events.

Replace the `id` attribute with class instead and use event delegation to bind the events.

Change your HTML from

```
<div id="subjectClickwd" 
<textarea rows="3" id="note"
```

to

```
<div class="subjectClickwd" 
<textarea rows="3" class="note"
```

Then change your event handler from

```
$('#subjectClick').click(function () {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.subjectClick', function () {
```